# Customize a property by using other property values while Marshalling through Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

For Example I have a sample Java object and want to marshal

```
@XmlElement(name = "itemName")
private String name;

@XmlElement(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@XmlElement(name = "Price")
private String price;

@XmlElement(name = "totalPrice")
private String total;
```

Here I want marshal such a way that multiply quantity with Price and want to assign that value to totalPrice

How can we achieve this using Jaxb? Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding

```
   @XmlElement(name = "totalPrice")
   private String getTotal(){
        return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(this.getPrice()) + this.getQuantity());
   }
```

and by removing

```
@XmlElement(name = "totalPrice")
private String total;
```